# FATAL EXCEPTION : main - My app doesn't work on android devices anymore, but works on desktop

Tags: android, crash, libgdx, stack-trace

This is the first time I have this problem and I absolutely don't know what to do.

I used to test my app on both virtual devices and on my phone and tablet. I tested it very often, like every 1-2h.
And at one point, it just stopped working on every android devices, but it still works on desktop.

On the android devices, it crashes as soon as I start the app, and I obtain this message :
"Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped."

And in the logcat, the stack trace shows a "FATAL EXCEPTION: main", I really need help to understand what is happening, and how to deal with this situation.

Thank you very much.

```
11-28 21:10:37.517: D/dalvikvm(613): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.premier.jeu.android/lib/libgdx.so 0x411998b0
11-28 21:10:37.527: D/dalvikvm(613): Added shared lib /data/data/com.premier.jeu.android/lib/libgdx.so 0x411998b0
11-28 21:10:37.527: D/dalvikvm(613): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.premier.jeu.android/lib/libgdx.so 0x411998b0, skipping init
11-28 21:10:37.617: D/libEGL(613): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
11-28 21:10:37.627: D/libEGL(613): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
11-28 21:10:37.646: D/AndroidRuntime(613): Shutting down VM
11-28 21:10:37.646: W/dalvikvm(613): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.premier.jeu.android/com.premier.jeu.android.AndroidLauncher}: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.createGLSurfaceView(AndroidGraphics.java:122)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:102)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:95)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(AndroidApplication.java:133)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(AndroidApplication.java:99)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.premier.jeu.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:16)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-28 21:10:37.656: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  ... 11 more
11-28 21:10:39.476: I/Process(613): Sending signal. PID: 613 SIG: 9
```

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116075/libgdx-animation-for-android/27117023#27117023

Comment: Oh My God ! Thank you so much !
I spent the last 72h checking my code, and I never expected that the problem could come from a ".TTF" that had to be a ".ttf".

Comment: @Opetion I'm glad we will solve precisely talked about it the other day, if your solution is to Opetion gives up vote to help others so thanks