# Can't run libgdx app on Android emulator

Tags: opengl, libgdx, runtime-error

I get this error:

> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0

I tried to change the target api and marked use GPU in the emulator configuration. but still get error. what else can I try?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703940/libgdx-helloworld-project-crashes-when-run-on-android-emulator?rq=1

Comment: I saw this and did all of this and still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve my problem so I used GenyMotion as Gregory Fein suggested.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Android are you trying to run on your emulator?  Just changing the GPU setting on the emulator may not be enough.  You have to be running Android 2.2 (API 8) or higher.  The emulator you're using may be using the wrong Android version.

Also, I'd recommend using the GenyMotion simulators over the built-in emulator.  They're much smoother.

Comment: Emulator Version is API 11, app configuration is 
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>